# Can I change owner of a tunnel after creating it?

Tags: ssh, python, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I've been trying to finagle [pytun](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pytun/2.0) to do my bidding in creating persistent ssh tunnels, but I very much do not want these to be owned by root and unless I modify the python package myself (which as a responsible person, I probably should) I can't use it to create a persistent SSH tunnel (unless I ssh as root), there's no notion of "ownership" exposed by the package.

What I want to do is either:

1. Create a tun interface using pytun ran as a non-root user and have it owned by that user in the first place.
2. Create the tun interface as root using pytun and then change ownership somehow. (from the help of 'ip tuntap help' I don't think this is easy)

Comment: you can't create tun interfaces as non-root user so the (1) is out.

Comment: @jak is that a best practice or a complete impossibility?

Comment: it is sane limitation in kernel: [CAP_NET_ADMIN is required for creating network devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt)

Comment: Network devices don't have "users" (or any sort of permissions), so this makes little sense.

Comment: @vonbrand run `ip tuntap add dev tun99 mode tun user vonbrand`